# Get the file from Dropzone.js to PHP controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, dropzone.js

Please someone can help me.
I turn in round since days. I tried many documentations and tutorial so please don't send me to it again. It doesn't work.

I try to implement the Dropzone.js tool in my project and get the file in PHP with Codeigniter.

My code doesn't work. I am close because I get something with the Javascript but I don't succeed to get the file with PHP.

Thank you very much by advance for the help.

I tried with AJAX.
I tried to create a form in many ways.

My view

```
<form action="creacion_curso" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
  <div class="dropzone dz-clickable" id="myDrop">
   <div class="dz-default dz-message" data-dz-message="">
      <span>Drop files here to upload</span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-confirm">Crear el curso</button>
</form>
```

My controller

```
public function course_creation()
{
  var_dump($_FILES['file']);
}
```

What the var_dump throw me

```
NULL
```

The Javascript

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myDrop", { 
   url: "creacion_curso",
   success: function(file){
     console.log(file);
   }
});
```

What I get in console

```
File {upload: {…}, status: "success", previewElement: div.dz-preview.dz-processing.dz-image-preview, previewTemplate: div.dz-preview.dz-processing.dz-image-preview, accepted: true, …}
```

Comment: your controller method is `course_creation` yet you specify a url `creacion_curso`. how are you getting anything e.g. NULL and not a 404?

Comment: I forgot, my route "creacion_curso" point to the method "course_creation" of my controller. For that reason I don't have a 404 error but null value.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you are not routing the data well. Make sure you have URL helper on autoload and then make these changes.

VIEW:

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('CONTROLLER/course_creation'); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
  <div class="dropzone dz-clickable" id="myDrop">
   <div class="dz-default dz-message" data-dz-message="">
      <span>Drop files here to upload</span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-confirm">Crear el curso</button>
</form>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
public function course_creation()
{
  var_dump($_FILES);
  var_dump($_POST); //Want to see if there is anything in this array
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myDrop", { 
   url: "<?php echo site_url('CONTROLLER/course_creation'); ?>",
   success: function(file){
     console.log(file);
   }
});
```